# How to perform tasks on completed downloads in the background?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I start a background download like this:

```
BackgroundDownloader downloader = new BackgroundDownloader();
var downloadOperation = downloader.CreateDownload(downloadUri, storageFile);
await downloadOperation.StartAsync().AsTask(cts.Token, progressCallback);
```

On app launch I get current downloads like this:

```
downloads = await BackgroundDownloader.GetCurrentDownloadsAsync();
```

The problem is that I see after relaunching the app completed downloads are in `downloads` list on Windows 10, but not on Windows 10 Mobile.

Don't we have any chance to do processes on downloads that are completed in the background while the app was terminated?

Thanks.

Comment: As I think you should still get those completed tasks as you return to the app. Nevertheless with W10 there is also other option - you may use *BackgroundTransferCompletionGroup* class - see [post processing at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/background-transfers#post-processing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this contains the information your looking for: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/background-transfers#post-processing